# Ability to step into a function is dependent on what managed function called it

Tags: c#, c, gdb, pinvoke

I have a managed class library written in C#. It uses p/invoke to call functions from a native library.

I have 2 test cases that I am currently working with. I am using clion (gdb) to debug the native portion of my app. Curiously, when I run the first of the two unit tests, I can't step into a function that I can normally step into when running the second unit test.

Example:
Say the call stack looks like this:

```
Managed Func -> native func -> another native func -> last one
```

When running unit test 1, I can step all the way into `last one`. When running unit test 2, I can only step as far as `another native func`.

So my question is, what could possibly be different about both unit tests that influences the availability of debug symbols for a native library?

Comment: You should create a minimal reproducible example or at least show the related code. Also, if by stepping you mean `step`, it might be that your native library is missing some debugging information, does `stepi` work?